# Actiontec Port Forwarding Configuration - Start/End ports for External (WAN) and Internal (LAN) options

Tags: router, portforwarding

Looking for some clarification as to the differences between the "start" and "end" port settings on my router, for the purposes of **port forwarding**.

I don't have enough 'reputation' to post a picture of my router port forwarding configuration page ...

So I'll type up exactly what it looks like here:

**Port Forwarding**

**1. Set the LAN/WAN port and IP information.**

Select LAN device:

LAN IP Address:

External (WAN) Start Port:

External (WAN) End Port:

Internal (LAN) Start Port:

Internal (LAN) End Port:

Protocol: (options: TCP, UDP, GRE)

That's it.

So, hypothetically, if I wanted to open up a home-based web server for users outside my LAN on port 80, would "80" be filled in for all the port options? What are the differences?

Answer (score 0):

change the access control http port number to anything as u need.. and then access your modem using that port number..
after doing this, you can put 80 as your External (WAN) Start Port,External (WAN) End Port,Internal (LAN) Start Port:,Internal (LAN) End Port.
This worked for me..:D